AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit. Error output: sur android studio en 2024
je suis nouveau dans le développement d'application sur Android studio et j'ai rencontré ca (AAPT2 aapt2-8.3.1-10880808-windows Daemon #0 Failed to shutdown within timeout )comme problème  que faire ?erreur rencontrer 
j'ai regarder et appliquer aveuglement une video youtube ou j'ai entrer cette ligne "android.enableAapt2=true"
enter image description here
dans le fichier gradle.properties , et j'ai aussi verifier si le targetSdk = 34 et compileSdk = 34  dans le fichier build.gradle et que tools:targetApi du fichier AndroidManifest.xml était a  "34"

pas de francais sil vous plait please check https://www.frandroid.com/ https://openclassrooms.com/fr/
